# Dask distributed perform computations without returning data

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a dynamic Dask Kubernetes cluster.
I want to load 35 parquet files (about 1.2GB) from Gcloud storage into Dask Dataframe then process it with `apply()` and after saving the result to parquet file to Gcloud.

During loading files from Gcloud storage, a cluster memory usage is increasing to about 3-4GB. Then workers (each worker has 2GB of RAM) are terminated/restarted and some tasks getting lost,
so cluster starts computing the same things in a circle.
I removed `apply()` operation and leave only `read_parquet()` to test
if my custom code causes a trouble, but the problem was the same, even with just single `read_parquet()` operation. This is a code:

```
client = Client('<ip>:8786')
client.restart()

def command():
    client = get_client()
    df = dd.read_parquet('gcs://<bucket>/files/name_*.parquet', storage_options={'token':'cloud'}, engine='fastparquet')
    df = df.compute()

x = client.submit(command)
x.result()
```

**Note: I'm submitting a single command function to run all necessary commands to avoid problems with gcsfs authentication inside a cluster**

After some investigation, I understood that problem could be in `.compute()` which returns all data to a process, but this process (my command function) is running on a worker. Because of that, a worker doesn't have enough RAM, crashes and lose all computed task which triggers tasks re-run.

My goal is:

- to read from parquet files
- perform some computations with `apply()`
- and without even returning data from a cluster write it back to Gcloud storage in parquet format.

So, simply I want to keep data on a cluster and not return it back. Just compute and save data somewhere else.

After reading Dask distributed docs, I have found `client.persist()/compute()` and `.scatter()` methods. They look like what I need, but I don't really understand how to use them.

Could you, please, help me with `client.persist()` and `client.compute()` methods for my example
or suggest another way to do it? Thank you very much!

Dask version: 0.19.1

Dask distributed version: 1.23.1

Python version: 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = dd.read_parquet('gcs://<bucket>/files/name_*.parquet', storage_options={'token':'cloud'}, engine='fastparquet')
df = df.compute()  # this triggers computations, but brings all of the data to one machine and creates a Pandas dataframe

df = df.persist()  # this triggers computations, but keeps all of the data in multiple pandas dataframes spread across multiple machines
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understand `df.persist()` is async. The main problem is that `command()` function finishes before the computations will be performed, so other tasks are canceled. There is a way to wait for `df.persist()` to finish computations, but not to gather data?

Comment: Okay. Never mind my last question. I have found `wait()` method in docs. Thanks one more time.